# In Renewal of iOS Program Enrollment id is missing

Tags: ios, iphone, renewal

While renewing iOS Developer program I have found Apple generated some Company ID instead of Enrollment Id.

I am enrolled to Individual since last 1 year not related to any company.

So, under Apple Developer Program Enrollment ID field I have to right down my Apple Email Id or something else ?

Comment: Who has voted as Off topic ? Tell me first the reason behind closing this thread. Only iOS developer's can answer this question no one else so its a genuine thread rather than a Off Topic. I request to all moderators please don't close any thread just like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your initial Enrollment id.
No need to write down existing Email Id instead of Enrollment id

Answer (score 1):

If you're **renewing** your developer license, you must enter your email address from the Apple ID associated with the developer account. Apple automatically generates a company id for every developer; you shouldn't have to worry about it.

Comment: Okay so under Enrollment Id field I have to just write down my email id attached to developer.apple.com Correct ?